# How to use WebDriverManager in selenium c# if the project is not in C Drive

Tags: selenium, exception

I am trying to use WebDriverManager to automatically download the compatible webDrivers with the browser versions :-
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
But WebDriverManager is giving me this exception :- "System.IO.IOException : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes."
It works fine if I place my project in C drive of my system but doesn't work if it is in any other drive. How to make it work even if project is located outside of the C drive ?

Comment: could you show your c# code?

Comment: Always mention version of package if there is problem to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem with WebdriverManager older version if roots were not identical but this is resolved with **version 2.12.1 released on 5th October 2021**. Therefore you should refer latest version then you won't see this issue. Here is the reference for fixed issue.

[Fix for error "Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net/pull/146)

[image]